# Get lines of file matching a regex

Tags: files, regular-expression, perl

Is there a more compact way to get lines of a file that match a regex than the following?

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";
 while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        next unless $line =~ m/^foo\/([^\/]+\/?)*==/;
        chomp($line);
        $line =~ s/==$//g;
        $search_result_set{$line} = 1;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to accomplish? Do not expect we will put effort to understand your script.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: How is the regex relevant? I was under the impression that it can be more compact in the read line by line part after opening the file

Comment: @Inian: Same comment as above

Comment: @RomeoNinov: E.g. I think there is something like `slurp` but that is considered insecure or something?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Regex is `^foo\/([^\/]+\/?)*==$`

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Updated post

Comment: `s{^(foo/[^/]+/?)==\s*$}{$1} && $sr{$_}++ while <$fh>`; in any case, do not write `/..\/..\/../` in perl, ever; write `m{.../...}` or `m#../..#` instead.

Comment: @mosvy:that works except that it keeps new lines in the end. So somehow `chomp` must be included

Comment: @Jim no it doesn't.

Comment: @mosvy: Then how do I get new lines?

Comment: @Jim add a `print map "<$_>\n", keys %sr` after it. No newlines.

Comment: @mosvy:Just did. There is a new line there

Comment: After `==$` there is no new line in the file

Comment: @mosvy: I added a `&& print "$_" &&` right in the middle and does not print anything

Comment: @mosvy: This works `chomp && s{^(foo/[^/]+/?)==\s*$}{$1} && $sr{$_}++ while <$fh>; `

Comment: You probably have something else in your script -- eg. set `$/` to something else than newline.

Comment: @mosvy:Is this like bash? Should I save the old value and reset it?

Comment: Yes. Make it local to the block. `{ local $/ = "\n"; ... while(<$fh>) }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @lines = grep s{^foo/([^/]+/?)*\K==\n?\z}{}, <$fh>;
```

Would store in the `@lines` array the lines that match the pattern with a trailing `==\n` removed. `$` matches both at the end of the subject and before a trailing `\n` in the subject, here we're using `\n?\z` (an optional `\n` followed by the end of the subject (`\z`)) for that newline to be removed if present, effectively doing `chomp`'s job. `\K` marks the start of the portion to be substituted.

Comment: So what about the removal part of the second regex? Should I go over the `@lines` a second time?

Comment: @Jim, I missed that part of the requirement. Then, it's even simpler. See edit.